# Configuring SSL in jboss 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, configuration, https, jboss

I am trying to switch my web interface from http to https for my ruby on rails web app. I did the following
1. Generated a certificate signing request locally
2. Obtained a keystore file
3. Obtained an SSL certificate from a CA
4. Imported this certificate into the keystore obtained in step 2.
5. Configured rails to use SSL
6. Configured a new https connector in jboss in the following way

```
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true"
    <ssl name="https" key-alias="myalias" password="foobar" certificate-key-   file="/tmp/keystore"/
</connector
```

1. Changed https port to port 80.

But when I load the application, I am not able to view the web application.
Note: There are no errors in the jboss logs

Answer (score 0):

How do you access your application? I mean the url pattern?
There will be conflict if you have same port for http and https connection.
Verify it in  section in standalone.xml file. Try changing https port to 8443 or 443 since you might have assigned port 80 for http connection.